# pathspec error when trying to commit

Tags: git, heroku

I am new to git and heroku. I am trying to commit new changes to index.php by:

```
git add . && git commit -am "test" && git push
```

and my output is

```
error pathspec '"\226am"' did not match any file<s> known to git.
```

I'm sure I am just typing a command error, but don't know what it is.

Answer (score 2):

I think your minus sign is not the standard, but maybe a UTF-8 hyphen or the like.  As a result, `-am` is being interpreted as a file name instead of an option.  Edit the command line, remove what looks like the minus sign and type in a real one.